# django error 'Fri May 26 15:07:37 +0000 2017' does not match format 'D N d H:i:s O Y'

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have the following date string:

`'Fri May 26 15:07:37 +0000 2017'`

I am trying to convert it with the following:

`fmt_date = datetime.strptime(created_at, "D N d H:i:s O Y").date()`

I get the error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Fri May 26 15:07:37 +0000 2017' does not match
format 'D N d H:i:s O Y'
```

I tested the format by converting backwards with the time now and it produces what seems to be the right format:

`fmt_date = format(datetime.now(), "D N d H:i:s O Y")`

`'Fri May 26 12:58:55 -0700 2017'`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you getting your `format()` function from? Your first call fails because that's not a valid `strptime()` format string.

Comment: You are mixing Django datetime format codes with Python format codes, which are not same. The backward works because you are using Django `dateformat.format` and in this case `D N d H:i:s O Y` is valid format. When you trying to use `datetime.strptime` you are trying to use some format codes which are not valid for `datetime.strptime` see this [table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)